# Codeigniter upload optional

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I looked for this in Google and different answers on stackoverflow. And probaly there is an good answer in them but still i don't get how i can implent it in my own code.

I got my own public function to upload an image, but now i want it to be optional. At this moment someone needs to upload an file to pass the validation, how can i make this optional?

my function:

```
public function _do_upload_image()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './company_images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_do_upload_image', $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    else
    {
        $this->_upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

--edit--

For other people, the answer worked and i gave my file_name an other name when there was no image uploaded. It looks like this:

```
public function _do_upload_image()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './company_images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
    $returnArr = array();

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $returnArr = array('file_name' => 'leeg.jpg');
    }
    else
    {
        $returnArr = $this->upload->data();
    }

    $this->_upload_data = $returnArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you need to make your upload function optional then you can just do:

```
public function _do_upload_image()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './company_images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
    $returnArr = array(); 

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $returnArr  = $this->upload->data();
    }
    return $returnArr; //just return the array, empty if no upload, file data if uploaded
}
```

Hope that makes sense

Comment: That works, but is there a way that if no image is uploaded i can give ['file_name'] the value: leeg.jpg ?

Comment: Uhm nvm, I got the problem fixed with all the functions i wanted. Ill update my post!

Answer (score 0):

> codeigniter file upload optionally ...works perfect..... :)

---------- controller ---------

```
function file()
{
 $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}

function valid_file()
{
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'File', 'trim|xss_clean');

 if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE) 
 {
    $this->file();
 }
 else
 {
  $config['upload_path']   = './documents/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|docx|doc|txt|rtf';
  $config['max_size']      = '1000';
  $config['max_width']     = '1024';
  $config['max_height']    = '768';

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('userfile',FALSE))
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('checkdoc', $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors());

    if($_FILES['userfile']['error'] != 4)
    {
        return false;
    }

  }
  else
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

i just use this lines which makes it optionally,

```
if($_FILES['userfile']['error'] != 4)
{
 return false;
}

$_FILES['userfile']['error'] != 4 is for file required to upload.
```

you can u make it unneccessory by using `$_FILES['userfile']['error'] != 4` , then it will pass this error for file required and 
works great with other types of errors if any by using **return false** ,
hope it works for u ....